# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type android.net.Uri

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an error that I can't found the cause, I have a User class that has an image (save as String and when I display the picture I convert the String to Uri, but I have a problem with the read from the firebase (the write works).

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User tempUser = ds.getValue(User.class);
                    allUsers.addToList(tempUser);
                }
```

The error is at this line:
User tempUser = ds.getValue(User.class);
Thanks!

FireBase:

```
  "message" : {
    "Users" : {
      "123456" : {
        "birthDate" : {
          "date" : 4,
          "day" : 4,
          "hours" : 0,
          "minutes" : 0,
          "month" : 10,
          "seconds" : 0,
          "time" : 61562584800000,
          "timezoneOffset" : -120,
          "year" : 2020
        },
        "bloodType" : "",
        "country" : "",
        "email" : "",
        "fullName" : "",
        "id" : "",
        "imageUser" : "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A435",
        "password" : "1234",
        "phoneNumber" : "0123456"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type android.net.Uri

Comment: Please also add the content of your `User` class.

Comment: public class User {

    private String fullName;
    private String ID;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String password;
    private String country;
    private Date birthDate;
    private String imageUser;
}

Comment: Please also edit your question add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.